# iOS: Implement a simple drag and drop to reorder

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have x number of views in a row:

[view1]  [view2]  [view3]

I need to be able to drag and reorder anyone of them (just in the horizontal direction), and also need to insert new views.

How would you implement this?

I guess something like this:

```
- (void)didDragView:(UIView *)currentView 
{
    for (UIView *v in self.viewsArray) 
    {
        if (currentView.center.x < v.center.x)
            // Move view to index: [self.viewsArray indexOfObject:v];  
    }
}
```

Comment: is this for a table view or anything such as that?

Comment: Nope, just for a card game. Simple UIViews

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this might help

http://undefinedvalue.com/2010/02/05/iphone-sample-code-tiles

However, you need some code change in order to support horizontal direction only

Answer (score 1):

you should use a collection view and this category:

[DraggableCollectionView](https://github.com/lukescott/DraggableCollectionView)